# Covariance matrix estimation when number of variables is larger than number of observations

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

It is well known that the sample covariance matrix estimator results in a singular matrix if the variables is larger than the number of observations.

One solution is to apply shrinkage estimators. Are there functions/packages in mathematica that perform shrinkage estimation of the covariance matrix?

I am looking for something that is comparable to the R package [corpcor](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corpcor/index.html).

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of using the corpcor package itself from within *Mathematica* through [RLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html)?

Comment: I have not used RLink yes .. could give it a try but I would prefer something inside mathematica only. Thanks!

Comment: Richard, do you have any links you could suggest to the description of an algorithm that would do what you ask?